# ORACLE - Update table if exists else insert use rownum to match

Tags: oracle

I have table master (A) without field ID_No. So i create table B (copy from A) and set B.ID_No = rownum.
Now i want update B if A exist else will insert B with B.ID_NO = A.rownum
In oracle can create query with B.ID_NO = A.rownum?
My logic is ID of B = rownum of A, row++ then ID++, row have change value then fields ID will update.

Answer (score 0):

For rownum repeatability is not guaranteed. You should find unique column or combination of columns for  key in tables A and B, for a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: I add pk_table1(field1, field2,field3), pk_table2(field11,field22,field33) is primary key. And use:
 MERGE INTO table2 B USING table1 A on ( B.pk_table2 = A.pk_table1) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET (...)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (...)
But result show error A.pk_table1: invalid identifier

Comment: You need write:
MERGE INTO table2 B USING table1 A on ( B.field11 = A.field1 and B.field22 = A.field2 and B.field33 = A.field3) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET (...) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (...)